# remove resharper files from svn

Tags: svn, resharper

i just moved a bunch of code into a svn repo and it checked in all of the resharper files and other items that dont need to be in source control.  whats is the easiest way to tell svn to ignore certain directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the [`svn:ignore`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3) property, I use the following in most of my projects root directory:

```
[Bb]in
obj
*.suo
_ReSharper.*
*.user
```

That will ignore generated files (*bin*, and *obj* directories), user preferences (*.suo* and the ReSharper's *.user* file) and the ReSharper directory.

Comment: can you do this through tortoisesvn windows explorer integration or must be done through command line ?

Comment: @oo, yes it can be done with TortoiseSVN: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html